# HTTPUnit Tests for Authorization

Tags: java, testing, authorization, http-unit

I am using HTTP Unit for testing my authorization framework.

I have problems when I try to test the cases after the Log-in, because the tests always check the first returned status codes.
When someone who is not authenticated tries to access a protected resource, the first status code is 401, he has the chance to provide his credentials and after log-in the status code is 200.

How can I program the test to perform the authentication and wait for the last status code?

This is how I did it until now. It failes, because the first status code is 401 and not 200.
Is there a keep alive option?

```
@Test
   public void testReqRestrictedResourceWithValidRole() throws Exception
   {
       // Request a protected page with valid credentials and valid role
       // protectedUrl requires role ADMIN
       // user has role ADMIN
       String username = "user";
       String password = "password";
       String decUserPass = username + ":" + password;
       String base64encUserPass = 
           DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(decUserPass.getBytes());
       webClient.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64encUserPass);
       Page page = webClient.getPage(protectedUrl);
       int statuscode = page.getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
       assertEquals(statuscode, 200, "Wrong statuscode.");
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell if the server side is not known. You might want to add a test case to HttpUnit itself showing your issue. I am a committer and would add that testcase to HttpUnit if it shows that there is something wrong with httpunit.